# Can “it is” always be shortened to “it’s”?

Tags: grammar, contractions

For example, can we change

> The car is blue, but the truck next to it is red.

into

> The car is blue, but the truck next to it’s red.

Comment: Not always. Contractions are not used in sentences where the word that would be shortened is significant, for example "I think it is." In your example, both occurrences of _is_ would probably be contracted. "The car's blue..."

Comment: This would be quite acceptable in informal 'BrE'. But not all prepositional usages are. */??'The equipment aboard it's cutting-edge.' And certainly not terminal usages such as *'I wonder what it's?'

Comment: The verb *be* usually takes a complement. If that complement is missing or doesn’t appear directly after the verb *be*, then that form of *be* cannot contract with the subject. Here, however the complement of *am* is the following adjective *red*, and so a contraction is fully grammatical.

Comment: In  "the truck next to it is red", _it_ refers to the car and not the truck. So it makes no sense to contract "it is" into "it's" in this example.

Comment: @KillingTime It makes perfect sense to contract is with “the truck next to it”, because that is the subject of the verb *be* here.

Comment: @KillingTime It doesn't hafta make sense; this is syntax. The only case where you wouldn't contract _it is_ to _it's_ is when _is_ is stressed, as it is in this clause. Normally, though, _is_ is reduced and is eminently deletable or contractable, and almost never stressed.